# How to get trace of method called

Tags: javascript

How do I get the trace of methods called in JS?

```
// file1.js
export const util = () => {
   // get the complete trace
   // from file2.js #start to file2.js #doSomething
}

// file2.js
import {util} from foo2.js

const doSomething = () => {
    util();
}

const start = () => {
    doSomething();
}
```

The only thing I can think of is to do `new Error().stack`... Is there a better way?

**Edit**

What if I want to see the filenames too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try console.trace()? That should do what you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/trace